# How to extract text between triple quotes using regular experssion in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am having following piece of raw string:

````
s = "###Sample Input\r\n```\r\n3\r\n100 400 1000 1200\r\n100 450 1000 1350\r\n150 400 1200 1200\r\n```"
````

I want to extract the text between the triple quotes which is `'3\r\n100 400 1000 1200\r\n100 450 1000 1350\r\n150 400 1200 1200\r\n'`

I am first converting this raw string into a python string and then I am applying following pattern:

```
pattern = r"Sample Input/s/s('''.*''')"
match = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(match)
```

But I am only getting an empty list as output. What is the correct regular expression to be used in this case for extracting text between triple quotes.

Comment: Maybe just `re.findall("```(.*?)```", s, re.DOTALL)` will do?

Comment: The line you're trying to read is commented out, no? Shouldn't it be a variable named "s"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still I am getting an empty list

Comment: @stever no the pound symbol is just part of the string and its not a comment. Yes actually it's a string stored in variable s

Comment: See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/YRd2qH).

Comment: Also, those are backticks not quotes... (not that it matters unless you're using it as docstring)

Comment: @stever yes thanks for pointing out. It is something called grave accent not exactly it is a quote.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much Sir. It works! First time I was not getting the answer as I was confused between ' and ` . But as @stever pointed out,  I did necessary changes and It's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

````py
```([\w\W]*?)```
````

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/hNftUN/2).

**EXPLANATION**

````py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```                      '```'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all
                             but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```                      '```'
````

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##TU7LCsIwELz3K5bmkoiUtLVH8ezZg4em0KKpDTQPtini18cEq3jYGRjmse7lJ2vqEJR2Fj2gzBY4Qk4IuQzazRLOxq1eoDB93yeqE5ScwyFe5AgV5z@x@Yp18xGbzVn9OWNVnunB3yaZ1lpdPNCujpYMRougQZn4STEqc1deIs1jgLbiKa7d7sRSeg8L6zKHyni6FbEQ3g)**:

````py
s = "###Sample Input\r\n```\r\n3\r\n100 400 1000 1200\r\n100 450 1000 1350\r\n150 400 1200 1200\r\n```"
matches = [m.group(1) for m in re.finditer("```([\w\W]*?)```", s)]
print(matches)
````

**Results**: `['\r\n3\r\n100 400 1000 1200\r\n100 450 1000 1350\r\n150 400 1200 1200\r\n']`

Comment: Thank you! It was a nice explanation and definitely solves the problem!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

````
yourstring.split("```")[1]
````

Note that this will give you the piece of text between the first two occurances of ```` ``` ````

Comment: This is not what I was looking for but it works!. Thanks